# How to get the transfer function of electrical network using nodal method

Tags: transfer-function, network, laplace-transform, mesh-analysis

We have the following circuit:

[image]

I am trying to get the transfer function using the Mesh Method. The first equation I've got is:

```
(s+1) I1(s) - sI2(s) = Vi(s)
```

The second one is:

```
-sI1(s) + (s + 2) I2(s) = 0
```

By that, the transfer function is:

2/(3s + 2).

The teacher used the nodal method:

and the result was:

1/(s + 2).

I know that using both methods, should give the same solution. Any help ?

Comment: 2nd equation is wrong.

Comment: Yeah. Its should be `-sI1(s) + (s+1) I2(s)=0` but still giving a wrong end result of V0/Vi

Comment: Answer is \$\frac{s}{1+2s}\$; teacher is wrong. Clearly DC gain = 0, since L is a short circuit at DC.

Comment: You can see that when \$s = 0\$, the inductor is a short circuit so your equation you should return 0 when \$s = 0\$ while for \$s\$ approaching infinity, the inductor is open-circuited and you are left with a divider exhibiting an attenuation of 0.5. This is the simple engineering judgment you must do to check your results.

Comment: Verbal kint can you explain more about what you said so I always check it on all transfer functions. Mr. Chu can you explain the process in an aswer ?

Comment: I agree with chu's answer. Your teacher is well-wrong. Dismiss that teacher!